# Чем можно заменить cout<<m<<endl; в java

Tags: java, c++

Что это значит и можно ли как-то аналог этого в java записать?

```
cout<<m<<endl;
```

Comment: Это вывод в консоль знач. переменной `m` и перевод на новую строку. Аналог - `System.out.println(m)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это просто вывести переменную в консоль и перевод строки и сбросить буфер (что бы накопленные данные попали на консоль).

Аналог в java

```
System.out.println(m);
```